# Frontend on rootdomain (Apache) Backend on subdomain (Node) -> Websocket connection failed

Tags: node.js, ssl, websocket, subdomain, proxypass

Here is my tricky problem:

I want to make my frontend and backend working on same VPS dedicated server.

- Frontend is an angular built app compiled to HTML, served by Apache with virtualhost on port 443 so that SSL is working on domain.com
- Backend is a node app using websockets (socket.io) running on port 3000, so I made another virtualhost with ProxyPass to redirect port 443 to port 3000, working on api.domain.com

Here is the result config:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName api.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.api.domain.com

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf


    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/

</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```

Everything works fine, except Websocket that shows error:

> WebSocket connection on wss://domain.com failed

By searching the web I found following config but it didnt worked either.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} Upgrade [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*) ws://127.0.0.1:3000/$1 [P,L]
```

Making further researches, I came up to the conclusion that websocket needs to be running on port 443 to work correctly. Am I correct ? or is there any solution to make it work on port 3000 ?

In the case where port 443 is required, how would I do to serve frontend and backend on both port 443 ? I sounds like just impossible, so I will probabely have to install frontend on another server...

Can someone can give me any advices about how to fix this problem ?

Thank you